# Error installing pyQt5: error: metadata-generation-failed

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

I was tring to install PyQt5 and a get this error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I've tried using `brew install pyqt` and installing pyqt6 went out just fine. What's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I faced this issue with python `3.10.4` and after searching I found two solutions for this problem because this problem not being only with turtle but for other libraries.

#Note: These solutions for downloading any library if you have a problem mentioned above and this problem faced me in windows CMD.

So you could try this way:

```
pip install <libraryName>==0.0.1
```

`0.0.1` This is the last version of the library so you should find the version of the library that you want to install for this purpose, you can find the version of the library using this command:

```
pip show module <name_of_the_library>
```

another solution that could work is using `--use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures`

Example:

```
pip install turtle --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: This leaves a problem though, because when I reinstalled python, `option --use-deprecated: invalid choice: 'backtrack-on-build-failures' (choose from 'legacy-resolver')` problem shows up. How can I solve that? @Jadallah